# MySQL SELECT query with LEFT and INNER joins duplicating returned data

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to create an INNER JOIN to connect multiple tags to a specific point of interest ID through a many-to-many relationship. While I was able to create this relationship in a query, it duplicates the multiple tags by the number of rows in a different LEFT JOIN, which has rating data. Additionally, the returned tag rows unintentionally increases the row COUNT.

```
SELECT
    loc.name AS name,
    sum(detail.d1) as d1,
    sum(detail.d2) as d2,
    sum(detail.d3) as d3,
    COUNT(*) as `total`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) AS tagName,
    FROM loc
    LEFT JOIN detail ON loc.id = detail.locid
    INNER JOIN loc_tag ON loc.id = loc_tag.poiID
    INNER JOIN tags ON loc_tag.tagID = tags.id
    WHERE loc.id = 1
```

This SQL query does return each of the tags to each point of interest record. However, the LEFT JOIN value results in the duplication of the tags as seen in the returned dataset. This LEFT JOIN joins more detailed rating data to the main query; in this case it pulls 3 specific rows from the 'detail' table.

| name | d1 | d2 | d3 | total | tagName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test | 18 | 26 | 18 | 6 | private,private2,private,private2,private,private2 |

The intended value should be the following, however I am unable to generate these results.

| name | d1 | d2 | d3 | total | tagName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test | 9 | 13 | 9 | 3 | private,private2 |

Does anyone know what in my query is causing this duplication?